# Smoke from passenger back wheel

Tags: ford, smoke, fiesta

Ford fiesta finesse 2003. I just got my car out garage yesterday having a cylinder fixed and couple leaked, one being brake fluid which went on my brakes. Anyway everything got fixed and today I noticed my passenger back wheel was smoking, there's not a strong smell coming from it so I don't think it's burning rubber. Can someone tell me what's going on here

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you get new brake pads as well as all the other stuff done you talked about? Were these ceramic pads? If so, the smoke could most likely be the pads curing. They'll smoke once, then should be good to go after. I don't know why shops don't tell the customers about this as I'm sure it happens all the time.

Comment: Do you notice if the car tends to slightly go to the right? As mentioned in the comment from @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it can be the brake pad also because it was installed not evenly or too close to the rotor.

Comment: They said they didn't have to change brake pads, cars not pulling right either. I was thinking could it be my handbrake not off fully when its off? As I have to give more gas on changing gear, but iv no hole in exhaust. I don't know what else to think, bar the handbrake?